# Custom Security Definition for Google Cloud Endpoints OpenAPI Key Mismatch

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-endpoints, openapi

When trying to set up the OpenAPI spec for Google cloud endpoints, I am unable to validate a JWT from Azure AD. When looking at the Endpoints Proxy logs, it appears that a key cannot be found for kid=HHByKU-0DqAqMZh6ZFPd2VWaOtg, however the x-google-jwks_uri clearly has that key included.  Am I missing something?

```
 "azure_ad": {
       "authorizationUrl": "",
       "flow": "implicit",
       "type": "oauth2",
       "x-google-issuer": "https://sts.windows.net/____/",
       "x-google-jwks_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/v2.0/keys",
       "x-google-audiences": "____"
```

}

```
E0906 21:08:43.470441462      12 auth_jwt_validator.cc:570]  Cannot find matching key in key set for kid=HHByKU-0DqAqMZh6ZFPd2VWaOtg and alg=RS256
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Endpoints currently requires that "alg" field must present in JWKS format public keys. But we are working on fixing the issue.

Comment: Can you provide any more details?  I don't quite understand what the issue is.  The header for my JWT includes an alg field with value "RS256", which is a standard algorithm for creating an asymmetric signature.   Does Google Endpoints not support this algorithm in their implementation?

Comment: Hi Paul, How did you fix it? I received exact same error. 16189 auth_jwt_validator.cc:606]  Cannot find matching key in key set for kid=z44wMdHu8wKsumrbfaK98qxs5YI and alg=RS256

Answer (score 0):

It worked after the ESP upgrade to latest version